# OAuth with Developer tokens

Tags: c#, .net, oauth, quickbooks-online

I'm trying to create an app with .net/C# that connects to quickbooks online using DevDefined OAuth.  However, I'd like to test with the single use developer tokens before going into production.  My issue is that I cannot find a single code example anywhere that describes how to connect to quickbooks (or really any service) that doesn't involve 4 different urls and five different keys, most of which I don't have.  So, can someone please describe the process and preferably post or link to some code examples of how to connect to a service using OAuth dev tokens.

Answer (score 0):

Start here:

https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0150_payments/0060_authentication_and_authorization/connect_from_within_your_app#/user

You'll need at least 3 URLs -- OAuth itself requires this:

- Request token URL is:  https://oauth.intuit.com/oauth/v1/get_request_token
- User authorization URL is: https://appcenter.intuit.com/Connect/Begin
- Access Token Request URL is: https://oauth.intuit.com/oauth/v1/get_access_token

You'll need several keys:

- consumer key
- consumer secret
- app token

You should have all of those already, since Intuit gives them to you when you register an application with them.

You can ignore this step entirely in the link above: "Step 2: Once the user has logged into your app, call the setup() function."

If you're having trouble, post your code.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to what Keith has mentioned -

Sample app link for .net using dev defined and all urls is mentioned below.

Go to https://developer.intuit.com/.

Create an app on out platform for the QBO v3 apis.

You will get a set of consumer key, consumer secret and app token.

Then implement Connect to Quickbooks button.

Set the above keys in the config of your code.

Then run the code.

You client who has the QBO company can then authorize your code/website to access his QBO company data using Connect to Quickbooks button.

You will then set of access token and access token secret and realmid/companyid to make api calls for their QBO company which is valid for 180 days.

To 'renew tokens', you can call reconnect api after 10 days or do Connect to Quickbooks after 180 days to get new tokens.

See the QBO v3 api sample app here-
**https://github.com/IntuitDeveloperRelations**
Set in your app keys in the config and test it out.

Also refer imp docs here-
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0100_accounting/0060_authentication_and_authorization
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0100_accounting/0060_authentication_and_authorization/connect_from_within_your_app
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0100_Accounting/0500_Developer_Kits

API docs-
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/api/accounting

Use API explorer to test out calls-
https://developer.intuit.com/v2/apiexplorer?apiname=V3QBO

Private publish-
To do a private publish, you need to go to your app dashboard->Your app and then click on Prod tab->All all urls ->Save->Then go to Keys tab under Prod to get the Prod consumer key and secret.

Apps.comhttp://Apps.com publish-
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0100_accounting/0008_release_your_app_to_production
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0100_accounting/0009_publishing_and_marketing_your_app